# If I run an infected DOS .COM file in DOSBox on C: directory will my main OS be damaged?

Tags: virus, isolation

I want to test some DOS viruses. If I run them from C: will my computer be damaged?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

DOSBox does not isolate your main computer contents from the files run within it. Thus, it could indeed damage the host.

*Probably*, it will only affect the files on already-mounted drives, so if you didn't mount any folder with non-discardable contents, you may be fine.

However, a malicious program could clearly run `mount drive: <folder>` and access <folder> of your computer from inside DOSBox.

You should instead use full virtualization for running your DOS virus (VMWare, VirtualBox…)

Comment: I'm not familiar with DOS, is mounting a drive something an antique DOS virus might do considering that DOSBox would (presumably) have been created much later in time?

Comment: @Numeron not at all. The mount command didn't exist on MS-DOS. The use of this command is specific to DOSBox. Still, it demonstrates that there is no security boundary. And when your Very Important Info™ is at stake, the risks are too high imho.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming:

- C:\ is your Operating System Partition
- You're asking if a virus run on your computer can inflict damage

The answer is: **Yes**

If you want to play with malware, consider an isolated environment like a virtual machine running [SIFT](http://digital-forensics.sans.org/community/downloads) or a malware analysis tool like [Cuckoo Sandbox](https://cuckoosandbox.org/).

You can also upload them to [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/) or research them on [Malwr](http://malwr.com).

Comment: "C:\ is your Operating System Partition" Not really. The C: seen by the virii will be provided by DOSBox.